# Executing python from within php

Tags: php, python

So my directory structure is like this:

```
parent_folder
    my_project
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
        models
            __init__.py
            a_model.py
        controllers 
            __init__.py
            a_controller.py
        utilities
            __init__.py
            a_utility.py
```

The way I'm executing my_project right now, is by launching a terminal in parent_folder and then executing the following command:

```
python -m my_project
```

This works fine. However, I wish to execute this from within a PHP script:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('python /path/to/parent_folder -m my_project');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Though, it's not working. Being new to python, I am just wondering what is the way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" - do you get an error message?

Comment: Well, the output from the python should be displayed. But nothing is displayed, so my guess is that that the way I'm calling my python stuff is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your error log, you'll probably see a message saying `can't find '__main__' module in /path/to/parent_folder`. You have to add "2>&1" to the command to make shell_exec return error output.

To replicate your way of running the project, you should change to the module directory with `cd` and then run `python`:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('cd /path/to/parent_folder && python -m my_project 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

An alternative is adding the path to your module to PYTHONPATH, which `python -m` uses when it searches for modules. You can do this in PHP before calling the shell, or globally on your system. In PHP it would be:

```
<?php
putenv("PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent_folder");
shell_exec('python -m my_project 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for!